# Skylake Integrated Graphics | HP ProOne 400 G2 AIO Install Problems

Tags: graphics, intel, display-resolution, integrated

Trying to install Ubuntu on HP ProOne 400 G2
It has an i3 Skylake and intel integrated graphics.

I have been unsuccessful in installing Ubuntu 14 - 16 and getting the graphics to work correctly with a decent resolution.

I have tried Ubuntu 14 w/ i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 (Kernel 4.2 - 4.4) <-- Did not work

I have tried Ubuntu 15 w/ 01.org Intel Installer (Different kernels too) <-- Did not work

Ubuntu 16 <-- Did not work

All versions do not show driver as enabled, and I have to put nomodeset in grub.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Could you please elaborate more what you mean by "have been unsuccessful in installing Ubuntu 14 - 16"?
Was the installation successful and you just did not manage to configure graphics correctly or the whole installation failed?
If you are able to install Ubuntu 16.04, try to replace installed kernel with kernel 4.6.3 (how-to below for your 64-bit installation), this should resolve your issues.

---

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.3-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.3-040603_4.6.3-040603.201606241434_all.deb kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.3-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.3-040603-generic_4.6.3-040603.201606241434_amd64.deb kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.3-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.3-040603-generic_4.6.3-040603.201606241434_amd64.deb
```

Install the kernel:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.3*.deb linux-image-4.6.3*.deb
```

Reboot your PC and check if kernel 4.6.3 is currently used by issuing command

```
$ uname -r
```